# How to make my letters not sensitive to the order of a word

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a hangman game which is almost complete but I have one problem:

I have a word represented by a array of underscores and the user must guess the word,however the words only get logged if it is guessed in the correct order.How can I make it will get logged no matter which order it is guessed

```js
function playgame(yourword) {
  //yourword array
  let word = yourword.toUpperCase();
  let letters = word.split("");
  let answerArray = [letters[0]];
  for (let i = 1; i < letters.length; i++) {
    answerArray[i] = "_";
  }
  let answer = answerArray.join();
  //hangman array
  let hgm = ["H", "A", "N", "G", "M", "A", "N"];
  let hgArray = [hgm[0]];
  for (let i = 1; i < hgm.length; i++) {
    hgArray[i] = "_";
  }
  //loop
  let remainingLetters = word.length - 1;
  let remainingLetter = hgm.length;
  let currentHangmanPosition = 1;
  while (remainingLetters > 0 & remainingLetter > 0) {

    //show the array
    console.log('*******************************************************************')
    console.log(answerArray.join(" ").toUpperCase());
    console.log('*******************************************************************')
    console.log(hgArray.join(" ").toUpperCase());

    let guess = prompt("guess a letter").toUpperCase();
    //adds a letter if guessed correctly

    if (letters[word.length - remainingLetters] == guess) {
      answerArray[word.length - remainingLetters] = guess;
      remainingLetters--;
    } else {
      hgArray[currentHangmanPosition] = hgm[currentHangmanPosition];
      currentHangmanPosition++;
    }

    console.log('Your word is' + answerArray.join(" ").toUpperCase());
    console.log('Dont spell out HANGMAN' + hgArray.join(" ").toUpperCase());
    console.log('*******************************************************************')
    if (remainingLetters === 0) {
      console.log("you win");
    } else if (currentHangmanPosition == hgm.length) {
      console.log("you lose");
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Example of what should happen:

```
playgame('Hello')
****************************
H _ _ _ _

// prompt - guess a letter will :
// if I guess o

H_ _ _ _

// if I guess e
H e _ _ _
//then I whold have to guess 'l' then 'l' then 'e'
```

Please help out

Comment: this line: `(letters[word.length - remainingLetters] == guess)` is only comparing the guess to the next in line. Try something like `(letters.indexOf(guess) != -1)` to check if a guessed letter exists anywhere it the letters array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @Gavin I need it to be placed correctly  (letters.indexOf(guess) != -1) makes your guess the next placed letter even if thats not its position

Answer (score 1):

a solution....

```js
const Page  = document.querySelector('main')
    , Quest = document.createElement('p')
    , L_In  = document.createElement('input')
    , btnOk = document.createElement('button')
    , HangY = document.createElement('p')

var HangWord = 'HANGMAN'
  , HangResp = []

for (let i=0;i<HangWord.length;i++)
  {
  HangResp[i] = { letr:HangWord.charAt(i), Resp:'_' }
  }

function setHangQ(zLetter)
  {
  let R = ''
  for(let hR of HangResp )
    {
    if ( hR.letr===zLetter && hR.Resp==='_' )
      {
        hR.Resp = zLetter 
        // zLetter = ''  for only one
      }
    R += hR.Resp + ' '
    }
  return R
  }

function HangComplete()
  {
  R = true
  for(let hR of HangResp )
    {
    R = R && hR.letr===hR.Resp
    }
  return R
  }

btnOk.onclick=e=>
  {
  let HangZ         = HangY.cloneNode()
  HangZ.textContent = L_In.value + ' --> ' + setHangQ(L_In.value)
  L_In.value        = ''
  Page.removeChild(Quest)
  Page.appendChild(HangZ)

  if (!HangComplete())
    {
    Page.appendChild(Quest)
    L_In.focus()          
    }
  }

L_In.onkeyup=e=>
  {
  let inTxt      = L_In.value.toUpperCase().trim()
  L_In.value     = (inTxt.length > 1) ? inTxt.charAt(inTxt.length -1) : inTxt
  btnOk.disabled = (L_In.value ==='')
  }
HangY.textContent = setHangQ('')
btnOk.innerText   = 'OK'
L_In.value        = ''
Quest.innerText   = 'guess a letter :'
btnOk.disabled    = true

Quest.appendChild(L_In)
Quest.appendChild(btnOk)

Page.appendChild(HangY)
Page.appendChild(Quest)
L_In.focus()
```

```css
p input { width: 20px; margin: 0 5px }
```

```html
<main></main>
```